# How to write a routing for a child module in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Help to properly configure the routing in the application on Angular
I created one main component - public.component. Using the  selector, the auth.component component is inserted from the child module Auth.module.
How can I write the routing for the auth.module module so that the modal windows are displayed?

[mycode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxzmab)

Answer (score 0):

Export all the components in the AuthModule.

You can write routing configurations in the app-routing.module.ts (whichever you have written in the auth-routing.module.ts)

If you are going to lazy load the module, you can do like mentioned in the link,

https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration